# Long range wireless antenna setup

Tags: wireless-networking, installation, antenna

I have a TP-LINK TL-ANT5830B 5GHz 30dBi Outdoor Directional Antenna. I have not try to install outside yet but I set it up in my basement. I thought I would pickup some signals however it only shows my ssid with a poor signal. So I wonder, this antenna must be install outside to work properly? I just dont wanna waste my time to install it outside before I am sure.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nope should work fine indoors or outdoors... its Directional so obviously stand in front of it.. also remembers its 5ghz so will only send signal for 802.11n & 802.11ac set to 5ghx not the older standards that are 2.4GHz standard... Your device your connecting via (phone, laptop, etc.) must also support the newer standards for 5ghz too...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in your situation, I do not think you will gain the answer you need until you test by setting it up outside. Setting it up in your basement wouldn't show full or exact signal strengths so the only possible solution is to set it up in the place you want it, and then you can see if it performs to your expectations or not.

Answer (score 0):

A 30dBi antenna means that when the antenna is pointing at the direction of the signal the power received will the 1000 times more powerful than a an omni antenna...  Conversely, if the antenna is not pointing in the direction of the signal, the signal will be coming in on sidelobes and will be attenuated by some amount large.  In an ideal world, around or greater than 30dB.

A note on orientation of the antenna, if the antanna is a parabolic dish, a 30dBi antenna nominally has a beam width of less than 10 degrees horizontal and vertical.  A Yagin and horizontal Omni have very different beam shapes.  My point is, you need to make sure your orientation is correct to get signal gain, and not attenuation.

Your basement probably has a great deal of multipath and potentially other phenomena (near field) issues.  As such, you will not get a full 30dBi (1000x) gain or loss regardless of the orientation, as part of the signal will likely come in through the sidelobes.

As stated in a prior answer, you will likely have to test this outside before you will know if this will work sufficiently for your application.

Answer (score 0):

"Tree" is a 4-letter word for microwave energy. So is "rain". If rain will interfere with an otherwise clear path, being in a basement amounts to "no signal" conditions, no matter how wonderful the antenna is. You need as clear a path as possible, which means up high (and using an excellent feedline and quality, properly installed connectors), unobstructed, away from nearby objects especially metal ones (multipath) and your antenna needs to be aimed precisely. If radio science was easy, everyone would be doing it. People have been putting antennas outdoors for over a century, with reason.